# Authenticity of a quote by Vivekananda

Tags: vivekananda, quote

I cam across the following quote

> Take Risks in Your Life ~ If you Win, you Can Lead! ~~ If you Lose,
> You Can Guide!

and many websites are claiming that the quote is by Swami Vivekananda.

Is it true that Vivekananda quoted it?

Comment: No he did not say. Proofs lie in the assertion, not in the negation. Those that say he said it should give a reference.

Answer (score 2):

I doubt the veracity of the quote. The quote does not catch the force in Swami Vivekananda's writing. He probably used this phrase several times in his public life. I am giving one example of it below. He always talks of strength and never of failure.

> Our poor people, these downtrodden masses of India, therefore, require
> to hear and to know what they really are. Ay, let every man and woman
> and child, without respect of caste or birth, weakness or strength,
> hear and learn that behind the strong and the weak, behind the high
> and the low, behind every one, there is that Infinite Soul, assuring
> the infinite possibility and the infinite capacity of all to become
> great and good. Let us proclaim to every soul: **उत्तिष्ठत जाग्रत
> प्राप्य वरान्निबोधत — Arise, awake, and stop not till the goal is
> reached. Arise, awake! Awake from this hypnotism of weakness. None is
> really weak; the soul is infinite, omnipotent, and omniscient.** Stand
> up, assert yourself, proclaim the God within you, do not deny Him! Too
> much of inactivity, too much of weakness, too much of hypnotism has
> been and is upon our race. O ye modern Hindus, de-hypnotise
> yourselves. The way to do that is found in your own sacred books.
> Teach yourselves, teach every one his real nature, call upon the
> sleeping soul and see how it awakes. Power will come, glory will come,
> goodness will come, purity will come, and everything that is excellent
> will come when this sleeping soul is roused to self-conscious
> activity. Ay, if there is anything in the Gita that I like, it is
> these two verses, coming out strong as the very gist, the very
> essence, of Krishna's teaching — "He who sees the Supreme Lord
> dwelling alike in all beings, the Imperishable in things that perish,
> he sees indeed. For seeing the Lord as the same, everywhere present,
> he does not destroy the Self by the Self, and thus he goes to the
> highest goal."

The Complete Works of Swami Vivekananda, Volume 3, Lectures from Colombo to Almora, The mission of Vedanta

Answer (score -1):

**This is the full quote**

> Arise, awake, and stop not until the goal is achieved. Take risks in your life. If you win, you can lead, if you lose, you can guide.

[This website](https://english.jagran.com/lifestyle/national-youth-day-15-powerful-quotes-by-swami-vivekananda-on-his-birth-anniversary-10007795#:%7E:text=Here%20are%20Swami%20Vivekananda%27s%20famous,you%20lose%2C%20you%20can%20guide) confirmes it. It is from Swami Vivekananda.It is from the book [Raja Yoga](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raja_Yoga_(book)),
according to [this](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/697385-take-risks-in-your-life-if-u-win-u-can)  website.

So the answer is **yes** it is by Swami Vivekananda

Comment: the two quotes are unrelated.  "Arise awake" is from उत्तिष्ठत जाग्रत प्राप्य वरान्निबोधत,
क्षुरासन्न धारा निशिता दुरत्यद्दुर्गम पथ: तत् कवयो वदन्ति |   the second line is an anticlimax after the first line @dark knight

Comment: The website is just claiming and they are not mentioning the chapter number etc.,